# Receiving 503 from aws lambda Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, aws-lambda, http-status-code-503

I'm having a problem when scrapping a website. I'm using AWS lambda to scrape cause its an unique website. I receive a request with a information that is used to access the website. It's succesfully scrape everything and return a json from the scr_consult function. However, It's not returned from the handle_request function. It's printed out before the return statement, but I receive a 503 (Service Unavailable) with no data in the request response.

The handler function, it is executed by the AWS lambda:

```
def handle_request(event, context):

event_body = event.get('body')

cpf = json.loads(event_body).get('cpf')

response = {"statusCode": 200, "body": {
    "response_bacen": scr_consult(cpf),
}}
print(json.dumps(response))

return json.dumps(response)
```

The selenium code that is executed and scrape the target website:

```
def list_split(listA, n):
for x in range(0, len(listA), n):
    every_chunk = listA[x: n+x]

    if len(every_chunk) < n:
        every_chunk = every_chunk + \
            [None for y in range(n-len(every_chunk))]
    yield every_chunk

def flatten(t):
return [item for sublist in t for item in sublist]

def merge_title_value(titles, values):
result = {}
for title, value in zip(titles, values):
    result.update({title.text: value.text})
return result

class WebDriver(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.options = Options()

    self.options.binary_location = '/opt/headless-chromium'
    self.options.add_argument('--headless')
    self.options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    self.options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    self.options.add_argument('--start-fullscreen')
    self.options.add_argument('--single-process')
    self.options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

def get(self):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        '/opt/chromedriver', options=self.options)
    return driver

def scr_consult(cpf_cnpj):

instance_ = WebDriver()
driver = instance_.get()

driver.get('http://microcredito.badesc.gov.br:8080/scr')

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/input"))).send_keys('login')

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/input"))).send_keys('password')

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/button"))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.ID, "gwt-uid-1"))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.ID, "gwt-uid-2"))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr/td/div/input[1]"))).send_keys(cpf_cnpj)

sleep(1)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='gwt-uid-11']"))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr/td/div/button"))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/button"))).click()

sleep(1)

titles_row = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
    "queryLabelTitleData")

values_row = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
    "queryLabelTableDataItem")

titles_table = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
    "queryLabelTitleMini")

values_table = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
    "queryLabelDataMini")

result_first_page = {
    **merge_title_value(titles_table, values_table), **merge_title_value(titles_row, values_row)}

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='gwt-uid-13']"))).click()

sleep(1)

titles = []
values = []
result_second_page = {}
for i in range(3):
    titles.append(driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
        f"queryTableTextValue{i+1}"))
    values.append(driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
        f"queryTableNumberValue{i+1}"))

    splited_values = list(list_split(values[i], 2))
    for list_value, title in zip(splited_values, titles[i]):
        result_second_page.update(
            {title.text: {"Valor": list_value[0].text, "%": list_value[1].text}})

driver.quit()
result = {**result_first_page, **result_second_page}
return result
```

It returns a Json with all the data scrapped. It is printed out on the AWS console on print in handle_request function, but it dont return it.
I receive this [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqYm8.png)

Comment: what is the output in cloudwatch? Any further information here? If not, try to use a try: except: inside your functions and print the complete trace (using traceback https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html). How do you invoke the Lambda? If using API Gateway, did you use the "proxy" mode or defined explicit request/response information?

Comment: It returns nothing on cloudwatch, just the json printed out on handle_request func. I'm using API gateway and I didnt use the proxy mode (didnt understand how it works). I've used Serverless framework to build a basic Python server on AWS. It configures by it self... @DanielSeichter

Answer (score 0):

### 503 (Service Unavailable)

The [503 Service Unavailable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503) server error response code indicates that the server is not ready to handle the request.

The most common causes of this error can be a server that is down for maintenance or that is overloaded with requests. The `Retry-After` HTTP header should contain the estimated time for the recovery of the service along a user-friendly page explaining the problem and should be sent to the user. 503 status is often a temporary condition and caching-related headers are sent along with this response.

Note: The [503 status code](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#status.503) does not imply that a server has to use it when becoming overloaded. Some servers might simply refuse the connection.

A simple solution would be to execute your test after a short interval.